# PDFLaTeX - Hide/Show textfield with ocgx

Tags: textfield, ocgx

I am working on creating a PDF document where I can show or hide the text field with a button. The goal is that I can use the text box to enter custom solutions, and when I uncheck the text box, a suggested solution is displayed.
Unfortunately, I'm not having any luck hiding the text box.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this. To generate PDFs I use PDFLATEX

Many greetings
Georg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ocgx2}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}

\begin{ocg}{My first OCG}{refmyfirstocg}{1}
\begin{Form}
        \TextField[name=file_no,width=5cm]{File No. } 
\end{Form}
\end{ocg}
\switchocg{refmyfirstocg}%
{\textcolor{red}{Click me!}}

\end{document}
```